# Wrting MATLAB Code related Laguerre Polynomial but getting errors

Tags: matlab, math, coefficients, pde

I'm trying to write code of these equations:

Laguerre Polynomial:
[image: Laguerre Polynomial Equation]

and Laguerre Polynomial Coefficients:
[image: Laguerre Polynomial Coefficients Equation]

So far I have written this MATLAB code of Laguerre polynomial:

```matlab
function M=Laguerre_Polynomial(N)
syms t k
for i=0:N
        x=factorial(i);
        y=factorial(k);
        z=factorial(i-k);
        A=((-1)^k * x)/(y*y*z);
        B=A*t^(k);
        L(i+1)=symsum(B,k,0,i)
end
Trans=transpose(L)
end
```

But now I’m facing difficulty in writing code for the Laguerre coefficients. How to attach `Laguerre_Polynomial(N)` function in the coefficients code?

```matlab
function D=Coeff(N)

syms t
f=t^3+t^2+1;
Lag=Laguerre_Polynomial(N);
for j=0:N
    C(j+1)=(int(f*exp(-t))*Lag(j+1),0,inf)
end
end
```

Error that MATLAB is giving me in above code:

> File: Coeff.m Line: 7 Column: 36
> Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Your mismatched delimiter error is because you put the parenthesis incorrectly. Change

```
C(j+1)=(int(f*exp(-t))*Lag(j+1),0,inf)
```

to

```
C(j+1)=int(f*exp(-t)*Lag(j+1),0,inf)
```

Comment: Okay Thankyou but my main question was how to attach a function from one m file to other m file ?